# Uppercase username in post

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm sending an email which signs off with the user's name. I've tried using `$uppercaseinviter = [ucwords ("{$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}")];` and `$uppercaseinviter = $_POST[ucwords ("{$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}")];`.

In the email body I'm just using `<p>{$uppercaseinviter}</p>`. The first method above sends the text in the email as `ucwords ("name");` and the second method sends it as `Array` with `Notice: Array to string conversion`. The first method gives a notice for undefinded variable `Name` so has uppercased it.

I can output the name in lowercase but I need the first letter of the name to be uppercase and I'm not too sure where I'm going wrong as the first method does uppercase, just not output and the second sends the word Array instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're adding too much to the code. The first you're making an array, the second you're trying to pull it out of $_POST. You don't even need the quotes and braces, it's just unnecessary. If the value is in PHP_AUTH_USER, all you need is

```
$uppercaseinviter = ucwords($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
```

Answer (score 0):

try `ucfirst()` - converts the first character of a string to uppercase.

- [W3 school](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_ucfirst.asp)

Comment: You linked to `strtoupper`.

Comment: man I think I can't answer on this site, I'll only ask